# Why do rabbits growl? Which animal did the nature intend to be intimidated by a growling rabbit?

Tags: rabbits

I know rabbits growl, but I don't know which animal did the nature intend to be intimidated by a growling rabbit.

Comment: [Jimmy Carter Maybe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jimmy_Carter_rabbit_incident)

Comment: Does that depend on the exact rabbit species? I had a pet rabbit for years and I don't recall it ever making any sounds (at least not in a frequency range audible to humans).

Comment: @JourneymanGeekOnStrike I don't know much about American politics, but how is Jimmy Carter an animal?

Comment: See the link - basically a wild rabbit decided to attack him.